# GLIBC not loading even after source compilation

Tags: command-line, compiling, glibc, chef

While I am installing chef , I am getting below error.

```
[root@centos Tools]# chef-server-ctl reconfigure
/opt/opscode/embedded/bin/ruby: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/libruby.so.2.1)
/opt/opscode/embedded/bin/ruby: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/libruby.so.2.1)
```

I have downloaded `glibc-2.14.1.tar.gz` and `glibc-2.17.tar.gz` sources and compiled manually with `--prefix` location as `/home/virt02/lib` but still no use. Getting same above error.

Update : I did

```
[root@centos Tools]# cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/randomLibs.conf
/home/virt02/lib
[root@centos Tools]# ldconfig
[root@centos Tools]#
```

Update :

```
[root@centos ~]# ldd /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/libruby.so.2.1
/opt/opscode/embedded/lib/libruby.so.2.1: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/libruby.so.2.1)
/opt/opscode/embedded/lib/libruby.so.2.1: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/libruby.so.2.1)
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffce97a7000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fab5317c000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fab52f77000)
        libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007fab52d40000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fab52abc000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fab52727000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fab53883000)
        libfreebl3.so => /lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x00007fab52524000)
[root@centos ~]# ldd /lib64/libc.so.6
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0151e36000)
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff952ee000)
[root@centos ~]#
```

But still not working.

Comment: Do `strace -f -v -s150 -o log chef-server-ctl reconfigure` and post `log` to pastebin.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/S598qt2i @siblynx

Comment: If your distribution does not provide newer glibcs to you (I am sure this is default and not going to be changed in near future), then you need to modify path to dynamic linker in your executables that load libraries that require those newer glibcs. Or run it directly with newer dynamic linker which must be somewhere in your `/home/virt02/lib`.

Comment: So please post additional output of `readelf -l /opt/opscode/embedded/service/omnibus-ctl/chef-server-ctl` to pastebin.

Comment: [root@centos Tools]# readelf -l /opt/opscode/embedded/service/omnibus-ctl/chef-server-ctl
readelf: Error: Not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start
readelf: Error: /opt/opscode/embedded/service/omnibus-ctl/chef-server-ctl: Failed to read file header
[root@centos Tools]#

Comment: @siblynx Hi ,Please find above attached output.

Comment: Not sure if my solution will ever suit you. Do you understand the basics of how dynamic linking on Linux works? And this is unfortunate that file was not an ELF - from strace, it looks like so, or I am too missy today :-(

Comment: Please post the output of `ldd /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/libruby.so.2.1` and `ldd /lib64/libc.so.6`. Thanks.

Comment: @DevNull Hi , thanks for responding http://pastebin.com/U65e8rDF

Comment: past the output of this command $ldd /opt/opscode/embedded/bin/ruby

Comment: @PKumar http://pastebin.com/A1LwT3iM

Comment: Have you tried setting all the env vars to the location of the .so? I.e. `LIBRARY_FLAGS` before compiling (linking, actually) and `LD_LIBRARY_FLAGS` before executing? If you don't set it I guess the system's .so is going to be used (might be of a lower version). In your ldd output, clearly `/lib64`'s libc is being used.

Comment: Can you do the following: `rpm -qf /lib64/libc.so.6` and tell us what package provides this library. My guess is that this `so` file is still from CentOS, which doesn't have GLIBC_2.14. You can check that by doing `nm /lib64/libc.so.6 | grep GLIBC_2.1`